# How to definitely turn off "display sleep" in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, power-management

After turn off "display spleep" it Power Management the screen continue to slow go dark after some minutes of inactivity. How/where to turn off this?

**--update**

On AC Power (I never use it on batery), the options and values are currently:
Put computer to sleep when inactive for: Never
When laptop lid is closed: Do nothing
Splin down hard disks when possible: unmarked
Put display to sleep when inactive for: Never

And it still is turning off the screen light after about 5 seconds..

Comment: Wow, that's terrible... how's a fellow supposed to keep the screen from dimming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Found](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/blog/archive/2009/05/01/adjust-or-turn-off-inactivity-screen-dimming-in-ubuntu.aspx), need to turn off the Screen Saver at System → Preferences → Screen Saver

Comment: Had same problem - this solution worked for me on 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want your display to never go dark, go to "power management", turn off "dim display when idle", and set "put display to sleep when inactive for" to never. That should make it so that the display will never, ever dim. Be aware that there is a separate setting for AC power and battery power, so make sure you set both so that the screen doesn't dim.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Unfortunately, there is no "dim display when idle" option here.. Please, see my update.

Comment: Sorry, it must be a problem with the OS itself.